# How to match a String in array of elements in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb, robo3t

I have a sample data like below where I want to pull the result with only data containing `Volvo`.

```
[
  'Volvo Sedan',
  'Volvo SUV',
  'Volvo Premium',
  'Volvo Sport',
  'Honda Sedan',
  'Honda SUV',
  'Honda Premium',
  'Honda Sport'
]
```

I tried something like this but it doesn't return any results. Could anyone please guide how to achieve it?

```
db.cars.distinct('carType', {carType: {$in: [/Volvo/]}})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) is used to compare value of the field in the document against array of items in the query, not other way round. E.g. to select all documents which have at least one `carType` that matches `/Volvo/` it's enough to do

```
db.cars.distinct('carType', {carType: /Volvo/})
```

Secondly, [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/index.html) operates with documents. First it applies the filter to match documents that have **at least one** Volvo in carType array, then it gets **all** carType in these documents and merges into single array with unique values.  E.g. if you have a document with carTypes

```
[
  'Volvo Sedan',
  'Volvo SUV',
  'Volvo Premium',
  'Volvo Sport',
  'Honda Sedan',
  'Honda SUV',
  'Honda Premium',
  'Honda Sport'
]
```

the first item matches /Volvo/, so all of them will be included in the result.

---

Assuming you want to retrieve a list with unique carTypes that matches your regex, you need to use aggregation framework. E.g:

```
db.cars.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$carType"},
    {$match: {carType: /Volvo/}},
    {$group: {_id: "$carType"}}
])
```